# How can we dynamically assign a document value in Spring using annotation?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I need to implement a generic methodology for different projects.
Code is:

```
@Document(collection="OT_analyticsTable")
public class AnalyticsTableModel {

    private long newUsers = -1;
    private long returningUsers = -1;

    public AnalyticsTableModel() {}
}
```

Here I want the document value to be decided at runtime.

Comment: I guess you can't... Maybe you may use this code http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#insert-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-

Comment: i saw it being done as per the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274019/how-to-configure-mongodb-collection-name-for-a-class-in-spring-data/34725975#34725975  but i am unable  to intimidate  it in my code.