# Create two collections from same POJO in Spring data mongodb

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

**Use case:** I want to have two collections which have same fields. One collection will have recent data (say 15 days)and other have old data(say last 6 months).
I want to achieve this with a single POJO as it will be easier to do query based on date and then convert it to VOs.

**Bottom line: I want to create 2 collections from 1 POJO.**

Please suggest.

Comment: do you have date/timestamp field in your POJO?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't think it is easily doable because the collection name is set in the `@Document` annotation which sits on your POJO. It is possible to change it dynamically by using SpEL expressions (see e.g. [How To Configure MongoDb Collection Name For a Class in Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274019/how-to-configure-mongodb-collection-name-for-a-class-in-spring-data)) and there are some examples where this can be used for [multi-tenancy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/1456) or [multiple principles](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/2776) but I don't see how to use this at compile time to create two different beans from the same class. To my knowledge that is not possible.

I can offer possible solutions but both are ugly af.

1. This is the workaround I actually used. Create child classes for the document and put the acutal logic into the parent

**Parent class**

```
@Getter
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal=true, level= AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CommonParent {

    @Id
    @Delegate
    HourlySiteWaiterRevenue.Key key;
    long count;
    @Field(targetType = FieldType.DECIMAL128)
    BigDecimal sum;

    @CompoundIndex
    @Value
    public static class Key implements Serializable {
        @NonNull UUID entityId;
        @NonNull Instant timestamp;
    }
}
```

**Actual model for repository**

```
@Document
public class UseThisForRepository extends CommonParent{
    public UseThisForRepository(@NonNull @JsonProperty("key") CommonParent.Key key,
            @NonNull @JsonProperty("count") long count,
            @NonNull @JsonProperty("sum") BigDecimal sum,) {
        super(key, count, sum);
    }
}
```

The model for the repository exclusively consists of boilerplate code that must be copypasted multiple times just so you can have multiple `@Document` annotations. This will by default use the child class name as collection name but is configurable everywhere.

2. `mongoTemplate` in principle has overloads with the collection name. It is possible to configure the collection name in the `mongoTemplate` (see e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template).  It should be possible to have different collection names and use those. However, I can't think of a way how to use this name in the classes Spring autogenerates from the `@Repository` interface. You could overwrite every single repository method in a `RepositoryCustom` implementation but then you could just not use `@Repository` at all.

Answer (score -1):

1. Considering you have similar POJO

   ```
   @Document(collection = "domain")
   public class Domain {

       @Id
       private long id;

       @Indexed(unique = true)
       private String name;

       private Date createdDate;

       //getters and setters 
   }
   ```
2. You can write `QueryMethods` in `Repo` to extract conditional data from a POJO

   ```
   public interface DomainRepository extends MongoRepository<Domain, Long> {

       Domain findFirstByName(String domain);

       List<Domain> findByCreatedDateBetween(Date thresholdDate1, Date thresholdDate2);

   }
   ```
3. Call `QueryMethods` in your controller/methods to get the desired
   collections

   ```
   @Autowired
   DomainRepository domainRepo;

   List<Domain> 15daysOld = domainRepo.findByCreatedDateBetween(15daysOldDate, currentDate);
   List<Domain> 6monthsOld = domainRepo.findByCreatedDateBetween(6monthsOldDate, currentDate);
   ```