# Any way I can change in runtime mongo document name

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

In the project we need to change collection name suffix everyday based on date.

So one day collection is named:

```
samples_22032019
```

and in the next day it is

```
samples_23032019
```

Everyday I need to change suffix and recompile spring-boot application because of this. Is there any way I can change this so the collection/table can be calculated dynamically based on current date? Any advice for MongoRepository?

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-525

Answer (score 1):

Considering the below is your bean. you can use @Document annotation with spring expression language to resolve suffix at runtime. Like show below,

```
@Document(collection = "samples_#{T(com.yourpackage.Utility).getDateSuffix()}")
public class Samples {
   private String id;
   private String name;
}
```

Now have your date change function in a Utility method which spring can resolve at runtime. SpEL is handy in such scenarios.

```
package com.yourpackage;

public class Utility {
  public static final String getDateSuffix() {
     //Add your real logic here, below is for representational purpose only.
     return DateTime.now().toDate().toString();;
  }
}
```

HTH!

Answer (score -1):

Make a cron job to run daily and generateNewName for your collection and execute the below code. Here I am getting collection using `MongoDatabse` than by using `MongoNamespace` we can rename the collection. 
To get old/new collection name you can write a separate method.

```
@Component
public class RenameCollectionTask {

  @Scheduled(cron = "${cron}")
  public void renameCollection() {

    // creating mongo client object
    final MongoClient client = new MongoClient(HOST_NAME, PORT);
    // selecting the mongo database
    final MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("databaseName");
    // selecting the mongo collection
    final MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("oldCollectionName");
    // creating namespace
    final MongoNamespace newName = new MongoNamespace("databaseName", "newCollectionName");
    // renaming the collection
    collection.renameCollection(newName);
    System.out.println("Collection has been renamed");
    // closing the client
    client.close();
  }
}
```

To assign the name of the collection you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274019/how-to-configure-mongodb-collection-name-for-a-class-in-spring-data) so that every time restart will not be required.

The `renameCollection()` method has the following limitations:
1) It cannot move a collection between databases. 
2) It is not supported on `sharded collections`.
3) You cannot rename the `views`.
Refer [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/) for detail.